Will changing the primary key to UUID in NestJS with SQL Server affect existing records?
@Entity({ name: DB_TABLE.ApiUsage })
export class ApiUsage {

    // @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    // id: number;

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;
}

I'm using the NestJS framework with a SQL Server database. I currently have an existing ApiUsage table with nearly 10,000 records. I need to change the primary key from id: number to uuid: string.
After updating the entity to use UUID as PK and setting synchronize: true, will the existing records be altered, modified, or removed?
My goal is to change the primary key to be UUID without altering or losing the existing records. (Note: This is not a production database.)

As this isn't a production environment, why not try and find out? That seems like the simplest way to find out.

Big question, why are you doing this? Numbers make much better PKs than Guids
